# Problems signing out with Devise in Rails 4

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm having problems signing out in my app.

The error that it's giving me is:

```
Template is missing
Missing template  users/destroy, application/destroy with {:locale=> [:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw,     :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. 

Searched in: *"/home/gregb/workspace/Sandbox/site/app/views" 
*   "/home/gregb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/devise-i18n-views-0.3.6/app/views" 
* "/home/gregb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/devise-3.5.2/app/views"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using devise, then that doesnt seem to me like the directory where the view exists. 
did you do

```
rails g devise:views
```

or create your custom views?
there's no destroy.html.erb file in devise.
but if you want to create one , I'd suggest you to create the destroy action in a newly created UsersController, then in the routes you have to place the

```
resources :users, only: [:destroy]
```

under the

```
devise_for :users
```

in order for it to be accessible. Then rake routes and find the right route. That should create the destroy action route for you.Create views in the app/views/users/destroy.html.erb and that should hopefully do it for you.